# How to generate a number from first or last digits of an array and check if it is divisible by a certain number in C#?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# and I am struck with this problem. To question is as follows

You are given an array of size n that contains integers. Here, n is an even number. You are required to perform the following operations:
1. Divide the array of numbers in two equal halves
   Note: Here, two equal parts of a test case are created by dividing the array into two equal parts.
2. Take the first digit of the numbers that are available in the first half of the array (first 50% of 
   the test case)
3. Take the last digit of the numbers that are available in the second half of the array (second 50% of 
   the test case)
4. Generate a number by using the digits that have been selected in the above steps

Your task is to determine whether the newly-generated number is divisible by 11.

And this is my code-

````cs
using System;
namespace IsDivisible
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int div = 0, digit;
            string str = " ";

            string[] numArray = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] arr = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);

                if (i <= n / 2)
                {
                    while (arr[i] >= 10) 
                    {
                        div = arr[i] / 10;
                    }
                    str += div;
                }
                else
                {
                    digit = arr[i] % 10;
                    str += digit;
                }
            }

            long newNumber = Convert.ToInt64(str);

            if (newNumber % 11 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("YES");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("NO");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}```

It has no errors during compile time in visual studio. The code is not printing anything after I input the array and I am unable to figure out what's wrong. Please help.
````

Comment: Your while-loop in the middle there never exits, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks mate. I removed the while loop and it worked.